Is it possible to create a alias to a man page?
On my macOS system I have installed gcc-14 with Homebrew.  On a shell that has access to the files, I can open a man page for the GCC compiler with man gcc-14.
I would like to write a script that specializes the shell and provide the ability to request the man page for the GCC version accessible to that shell with man gcc.
Homebrew installs:

gcc inside /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/bin and the executable is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/bin/gcc-14
the man files are inside /opt/homebrew/share/man/ which holds the man1 directory.

That holds /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/gcc-14.1 which is a relative symlink to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcc-14.1



I tried creating a /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcc.1 symlink to the /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcc-14.1 man file and included the proper directory in PATH to allow manpath to find the directory (which it does), but I can only access the GCC man page with ``man gcc-14`.
That did not work.  I could solve my problem by creating a symlink to gcc.1 inside /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/ but that would make a gcc man page available in all shells.  That's not what I want; I want to be able to use gcc 9 inside another shell and access its gcc 9 related man file inside that oath shell.
Perhaps the only way is to not rely on manpath and simply prepend the directory where the version specific gcc.1 man file is located to the MANPATH environment variable.
Overall, I'd like to have the ability to use shells that are specialized for different C/C++ toolchains.  On macOS, the default, non-specialized shell would use the Apple clang, which is what /usr/bin/gcc is.  So by creating a directory (like ~/bin/gcc-14 that holds symlinks to the Homebrew-installed GCC-14 binaries, and by having a ~/bin/gcc-14/gcc symlink pointing to the Homebrew installed GCC 14 executable, and placing ~/bin/gcc-14 at the beginning of the PATH of a shell, then inside that shell gcc is GCC-14, not the Apple-built clang.  I want to do something similar for man.
Any suggestions?

man doesn’t look at PATH — try MANPATH.

Wait — I don’t understand what you’re saying.  What do you mean by “I … included the proper directory in PATH to allow manpath to find the directory”?  (What do you mean by “manpath”?)  What do you mean by “(which it does)”?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

I tried to better explain.  I know that man does not look at PATH.  However manpath builds a list of man-specific directories by looking at several places (/etc/man.conf, /usr/local/etc/man.d/*.conf system config, local ~/.manpath config if it exists) and it looks at the man directories of directories identified by PATH.  So setting MANPATH ever explicitly you normally add to what manpath (or manpath -g`) returns.

You see, I'd like to have the ability to use shells that are specialized for different C/C++ toolchains.  On macOS, the default, non-specialized shell would use the Apple clang, which is what /usr/bin/gcc is.  So by creating a directory (like ~/bin/gcc-14 that holds symlinks to the Homebrew-installed GCC-14 binaries, and by having a ~/bin/gcc-14/gcc symlink pointing to the Homebrew installed GCC 14 executable, and placing ~/bin/gcc-14 at the beginning of the PATH of a shell, then inside that shell gcc is GCC-14, not the Apple-built clang.  I want to do something similar for man.

The solution to my problem was simple, given that no error is made in the targets of the various symlinks (...).

I created ~/bin/gcc-14/man/man1 and the other manX directories.

Inside those I created symlinks to the proper man.X files.

For example, I created a gcc.1 symlink to the gcc-14.1 file


When setting the shell, the sourced script does:
MANPATH="$HOME/bin/gcc-14/man:$(manpath)"
export MANPATH



The real man page files are located inside /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/.
So the ~/bin/gcc-14/man/man1 directory has to have the following symlinks:
- cpp.1@       -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/cpp-14.1
- g++.1@       -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/g++-14.1
- gcc.1@       -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcc-14.1
- gcov-dump.1@ -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcov-dump-14.1
- gcov-tool.1@ -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcov-tool-14.1
- gcov.1@      -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gcov-14.1
- gfortran.1@  -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/gfortran-14.1
- lto-dump.1@  -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/share/man/man1/lto-dump-14.1

